# IDE update failed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOmfS.png)Unfortunately, the IDE is not capable of an automatic update on your system.
Please quit the IDE and apply the patch manually by launching this script:
C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd.

[Here is what the Android Studio says about that update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzkET.png)

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try uninstalling android studio and then reinstall the new version

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the latest version which is working on my computer as versions after 3.6 do not

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, It requires a patch that can be added by launching this script: `C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd.`

OR this script:

`C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd`

Close the IDE (Android Studio)

And try the following commands in cmd.exe.

Click [Windows Key] + R & Type CMD then click OK, Then run the script.
If it worked, Turn on the IDE and try the update again.

Comment: 1) C:\Users\Пользователь>C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd
The system cannot find the path specified.

2)C:\Users\Пользователь>C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd.
'C:\Users\Пользователь\android-studio-3.6.3-patch.cmd.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I tried both of them. I just edited the post, I got what Android Studio says about the update

Comment: The plugins you're trying to add isn't compatible with the update. That's why